# Persisting the Order of Draggable Task Cards to a Database

Tags: javascript, python, html, sqlite, fastapi

I'm working on a web application where users can create, delete, and reorder task cards via drag-and-drop. The frontend is built with HTML/CSS and JavaScript, and the backend uses FastAPI with a SQLite database for persistence. My challenge is in persisting the order of these task cards in the database after they've been reordered on the frontend.

The task cards are dynamically generated from data fetched from the backend, where each task has a unique ID. However, the database schema does not include a field to track the order of these tasks. When a user reorders the cards on the frontend, I need to update the backend to reflect this new order.

Here's a simplified version of my task data structure:

```
{
  "2": {
    "count": "2",
    "country": null,
    "site": "Siteabber",
    "link": "https://www.sitejabber.com/reviews/emarket-24.com",
    "review": null,
    "rating": "5 stars",
    "nick name": null,
    "manager": "M1",
    "language": "EN",
    "published": "LIVE",
    "task_order": 1
  },
  "3": {
    "count": "3",
    "country": null,
    "site": "Trustedrvie",
    "link": "https://trustedrevie.ws/reviews/emarket-24.com",
    "review": null,
    "rating": "4-stars",
    "nick name": null,
    "manager": "M1",
    "language": "EN",
    "published": "LIVE",
    "task_order": 2
  }
}
```

Frontend:

I use vanilla JavaScript for drag-and-drop and send the new order back to the server via a POST request. I capture the order as an array of task IDs.

Here is my front end that is responsive for moving the cards:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      const taskboards = document.getElementById('taskboard-grid');
      let selectedCard = null; // Variable to store the selected card
  
      // Event listener for double-click to select a card
      taskboards.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
          if (e.target.classList.contains('task-card')) {
              if (selectedCard) {
                  // Deselect previously selected card
                  selectedCard.classList.remove('selected');
                  console.log('Deselected card:', selectedCard); // Debugging log
              }
              // Mark new selected card and add any visual indication if needed
              selectedCard = e.target;
              selectedCard.classList.add('selected');
              console.log('Selected card:', selectedCard); // Debugging log
          }
      });
  
      // Event listener for click to place the selected card before clicked card
      taskboards.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          if (selectedCard && e.target.classList.contains('task-card') && selectedCard !== e.target) {
              // Move selected card before the clicked card
              e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(selectedCard, e.target);
              selectedCard.classList.remove('selected'); // Remove selection from moved card
              console.log('Moved selected card before:', e.target); // Debugging log
              selectedCard = null; // Reset selected card variable
              updateTaskOrder(); // Call function to update order in the backend
          }
      });
  
      function updateTaskOrder() {
        const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task-card');
        const taskOrder = Array.from(tasks).map(task => task.dataset.taskId);
    
        fetch('/update-order', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ order: taskOrder })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log('Order updated successfully'))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error updating order:', error));
    }
    
    
    
  });
```

Backend:

My FastAPI backend receives the new order. I'm unsure how to best update the database.

Here is my backend:

```
@app.post("/update-order")
async def update_order(order: List[str] = Body(...)):
    try:
        db.updateTaskOrder(order)
        return {"message": "Order updated successfully."}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))





def updateTaskOrder(self, order):
        with self.global_db:
            cursor = self.global_db.cursor()
            for idx, task_id in enumerate(order, start=1):
                cursor.execute("UPDATE taskboard SET task_order = ? WHERE id = ?", (idx, task_id))
            self.global_db.commit()
```

Now, when I try the code, it returns me 422 Unprocessable Entity

Question:

How can I persist the order of tasks in the database after reordering them on the frontend?
Is there a best practice for handling this kind of dynamic ordering with SQLite and FastAPI?

What I've Tried:

I thought about using an auxiliary table to map order to task IDs but am unsure if this is the most efficient approach.
I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to tackle this problem effectively.

Comment: The body of the 422 error will tell you what field is missing or has the wrong type of content; start by looking at that.

Comment: Yes, I am trying my best, but unfortunately I struggle for now...

Comment: Add the body to your question if you need help interpreting what it's saying.

Comment: You mean the Body from the HTML?

Comment: No, the body of the response from FastAPI (where you're getting the 422 error) - that response body will contain information about which part of the validation of the request that failed.